# Problems using pyinstaller flask-desktop

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I cannot generate my setup with pyInstaller. When I type command "`pyinstaller -w -F myfile.py`" here is error below:

```
app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork)
12552 ERROR: Can not find path /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork)
12552 ERROR: Can not find path /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork)
12552 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork)
12552 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork)
12553 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork)
12554 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQmlModels.framework/Versions/5/QtQmlModels)
12554 ERROR: Can not find path /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQmlModels.framework/Versions/5/QtQmlModels)
12554 ERROR: Can not find path /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQmlModels.framework/Versions/5/QtQmlModels)
12554 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQmlModels.framework/Versions/5/QtQmlModels)
12557 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick)
12557 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick)
12557 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick)
12557 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick)
12558 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick)
12558 ERROR: Can not find path /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick)
12558 ERROR: Can not find path /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (needed by /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick)
12558 ERROR: Can not find path /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (needed by
```

Comment: Can you type/ copy paste the error please.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command to make your installer: `pyinstaller -w -F myfile.py --hidden-import=PyQt5`

If that doesn't work, you could try adding this line: `import PyQt5` at the start of the file.

This may make PyInstaller detect the `PyQt5` dependency.